# vercel nextjs api routes: ENOENT: no such file or directory writeFile

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, serverless, vercel

I have a Next.js application where users can input smartcontract(solidity language) code on the frontend. I need to compile this code using Hardhat(cli interface) and it writes the compiled artifacts to the server's file system and then returns the contents of it to the frontend via the same API. Locally, I've been able to achieve this by executing commands through child processes and writing the artifacts to a specified directory.

However, when deploying my application to Vercel, which uses serverless functions for api routes, I encountered some challenges. The serverless function directory is read-only, preventing me from writing files to it during runtime. Additionally, during the build process, the contracts directory and Hardhat configuration file (hardhat.config.js) are not included.

I'm seeking advice on how to work around these limitations.